# Definition of $\nabla f(ux_n - S(t))$ on a Banach space

Tags: definition, banach-spaces, lipschitz-functions, gateaux-derivative

Suppose $X$ is a Banach space and $f$ is a Lipschitz Gateaux differentiable function on $X$. Let $S : [0,1]^{\mathbb{N} \backslash \{ n \}} \rightarrow X$. Then we have

> $$f(x_n + S(t)) - f(S(t)) = \int_0^1{\langle \nabla f(ux_n - S(t)), x_n \rangle} du$$

The equation above is taken from [here](http://kaltonmemorial.missouri.edu/docs/sm2003c.pdf), page $128$.

Question: what is the definition of $\nabla f(ux_n - S(t))$ and why requires $f$ to be Lipschitz Gateaux differentiable?

I need to understand it so that I may know how the author obtains $\| \nabla f(y) \|_{X^*} \leq \| f \|_{Lip}$.

Comment: Gateaux differentiable means that the directional derivatives exist, and the notation used here means 'the directional derivative in the direction $x_n$'.

Comment: So the inner product $\langle \nabla f(ux_n - S(t)), x_n \rangle$ refers to Gateaux differential of $f$?

Comment: I don't think that language is helpful to you: the proof is saying the following. If $g(u) = f(u x_n + S(t))$ then the fundamental theorem of Calculus says that $\int_0^1 g'(u) \, du = g(1) - g(0)$. The existence of $g'$ is what Gateaux differentiability means, and here it is written $\langle \nabla f(ux_n - S(t)), x_n \rangle$ in agreement with finite dimensions. Thinking of it as 'the gateaux differential' isn't necessarily all that useful (at least, to me.)

Comment: Do you have any reference on what you stated above? I would like to polish my knowledge on gateaux differentiability.

Comment: Geometric nonlinear functional analysis by Lindenstrauss/Benyamini (which is one of the books the paper references) is likely to contain more than you ever wanted to know about Gateaux differentiability. I honestly don't remember if it contains a section on basics though. It also is the thing referenced later in the proof for 'we need the fact that these things are weak star dense'

Comment: May I ask what you're trying to get out of this paper? You've asked several questions about it, but I'm not really sure to what end. (I've incidentally been reading the paper this week.)

Comment: I am trying to understand the paper and also polish my knowledge.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31132/discussion-between-james-kilbane-and-idonknow).